# Inquiry about the Consdb integration with Grafana plugin

Tags: cnosdb

Are the Grafana plugins not signed? Grafana version 10.0.3.

[image]

I also tried a lower version just now. After installing it, it was still green. But it doesn't work when I try to create a datasource.

Have you encountered this situation before?